# RDS MySQL Cluster: Cannot Grant SET_USER_ID

Tags: amazon-rds, mysql-8.0

On an RDS MySQL 8.0.33 cluster, I'm trying to grant the [SET_USER_ID privilege](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_set-user-id) to a `migrations@%` User so that that account can change the DEFINER on some views.  I'm using the Master account, `root`, which has the GRANT OPTION.

Here is the grant statement I'm issuing:

```
GRANT SET_USER_ID ON *.* TO 'migrations'@'%';
```

That results in the following error:

```
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the GRANT OPTION privilege(s) for this operation
```

Again, I'm using the Master account, which does have the GRANT OPTION:

[image]

```
SELECT CURRENT_USER;
SHOW GRANTS FOR CURRENT_USER;
```

```
root@%
```

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, PROCESS, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER, CREATE ROLE, DROP ROLE ON *.* TO `root`@`%` WITH GRANT OPTION
```

I have two additional RDS MySQL 8.0.33 databases where I was successfully able to grant the SET_USER_ID privilege using the Master account.  The only difference I'm aware of is that those two databases are single instances, not clusters.

I've tried creating a new user with the grant option, and using that account to grant the SET_USER_ID privilege.  That failed.  I also tried setting the `log_bin_trust_function_creators` to 1